# "SelectedValue" of comboBox in WPF has correct value but with additional text of namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

"SelectedValue" of comboBox in WPF has correct value but with additional text of namespace. I am following MVVM, "SelectedValue" is binded to "SelectedImage" property.

If I select first comboBoxItem, its value is "**System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox:Firmware Image 1**".

**How to get only selected value?**

```
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Width="150"
              Height="30"
              ToolTip="Store Identification"
              Margin="0,2,10,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Background="#FF1649A0"
              BorderBrush="White"
              Foreground="White"

              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedImage}">
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Firmware Image 1 " />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Firmware Image 2" />
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strings, there you go:

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
          Width="150"
          Height="30"
          ToolTip="Store Identification"
          Margin="0,2,10,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Background="#FF1649A0"
          BorderBrush="White"
          Foreground="White"
           SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedImage}" >
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <sys:String>Firmware Image 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Firmware Image 2</sys:String>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
```

Add the namespace:

```
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the items to a `List` or `ObservableCollection` you're done.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedImage}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Firmware Image 1", "Firmware Image 2" }; 
public string SelectedImage { get; set; } //Maybe implemented with Notify for Two-Way Binding
```

**EDIT (second possibility): **

If you like to keep your items defined in xaml you could easyly use this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="DisplayText1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="DisplayText2" />
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

viewmodel:

```
//to get the text use: (SelectedImage as ComboBoxItem).Content
public object SelectedImage { get; set; }
```

Bind to an object in codebehind and you can perform the `Content` property.